# How to Iterate through Excel Sheets Data to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want efficiently iterate through the Excel-Sheet to DataGridView. How to modify the following code fragment: (string.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", s) to loop the Tables in the first Excel-Sheet(Excel1.xls)?.This is the code i have so far. I am grateful for any advice!

```
  TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
  TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();

  textBox1.Text = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Excel1.xls";

  string[] s;
  s = new string[2] { "Table1", "Table2" };

  String constr = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + 
  textBox1.Text + " ; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        
 for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
 {
    if (s[0] == "Table1")
    {
     OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", s), con);

     DataTable data = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(data);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
     //condition1...
    }

  for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
  {
     if (s[1] == "Table2")
     {
      OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("Select * From [{1}$]", s), con);
      DataTable data = new DataTable();
      sda.Fill(data);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
      //condition2...
     }
  }

 }
```

Comment: The worksheet in excel are tables in the oleDb library and the sheet names have a dollar sign at the end : From [" + textBox2.Text + "$].  So to iterate through the sheets you would need to change the value of textBox.Text to each of the sheet names.

Comment: thank you jdweng! should the change to be done before the foreach loop?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you implement as long as you get each sheet.

Comment: There appears to be disconnect in what you are wanting to do. For starters, the code appears to be overwriting the previously read workbook in the `dataGridView1`. Therefore, the grid will only contain the last workbook in the array. This is awkward, I am guessing you may want to put each `DataTable` into a `DataSet`? The next questionable code… `textBox1.Text = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" + ExcelSheet;` ??? `ExcelSheet` is a string array `string[]`… shouldn’t the code be… `textBox1.Text = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" + s;`?

Comment: Hi, jdweng and JohnG. I apologize for the late response. The idea behind it is much bigger. After entering a search term in a TexBox, the search will be performed in the ExcelSheets. A search term that is found in one or both ExcelSheets should be displayed in a ListBox. I was concerned to find a way, to loop through the Excel-Sheets. I have to admit that i still have some doubts about this, if it works. However, i would like to thank you for all your remarks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment… _”I was concerned to find a way, to loop through the Excel-Sheets. I have to admit that i still have some doubts about this,…”_ ? … The current code will successfully loop through both workbooks in the `string[] ExcelSheet = { "Excel1.xls", "Excel2.xls" };` … IF you code this properly…. you are not coding this properly so it is not surprising that you have doubts.

Comment: As I stated already, in the for each loop … `foreach (string s in ExcelSheet)…` … this is fine… with “each” iteration the variable `s` is assigned one of the strings in the array. The problem is the next line of code… `textBox1.Text = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" + ExcelSheet;` ?... this is incorrect and will never work as you expect. Why? Because `ExcelSheet` is a `string` ARRAY… NOT a single `string`. In this case the text in the text box will look something like…”C:\Users\Desktop\Test\System.String[]”. Look at my previous comment to see what WILL work in the for each loop.

Comment: JohnG, now I’ve understood you. I have adjusted the code. The code works, if two additonal FOR Loops are integrated. Maybe it isn’t so nice, but it works. It would be reasonable here to add that the code could be more compactly represented. How to modify the following code fragment:  (string.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", s) to loop the Excel-Sheets?

Comment: Posting the code as comments is not what you want to do. It is hard to read. Please move the code in the comments to your original question. Click the "edit" link under the question and add the code there. Then delete the code comments.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are over complicating things. Also, it is unclear what you want to do “after” you get the data from the Excel worksheet. The title to your question is a little confusing…

… *”How to Iterate through Excel Sheets Data to DataGridView?”*

It is confusing in a sense that the `DataGridView` can only hold ONE (1) worksheet at a time. In your current code, at the end of the `foreach` loop there is a line of code…`dataGridView1.DataSource = data;`? This is odd because once the grids data source has been set, the code loops back up and will replace it with the next workbook in the list. You will end up with the grid showing the last workbook in the list and the previously read workbooks are well… lost.

Given this, I will assume that you want to keep and not lose those previously read workbooks. This can be done using a `DataSet`. With each workbook read, we will add that `DataTable` to the `DataSets` `Tables` collection instead of assigning it to the grid. This way, “after” you have read all the workbooks, you can display any one of tables into the grid.

Next it is unclear “why” the code is adding the Excel file path and worksheet name into text boxes. This seems odd and to simplify things, the code below uses simple strings for the file path and worksheet names.

Next, whenever you open Excel or other objects in your code it is proper to make sure those objects are release or closed. In this case, we want to make sure the `OleDbConnection` object gets closed when the code exits. If everything works without errors, a `using` statement is a good approach and will close the connection for you. Then, the entire code is wrapped in a `try/catch/finally` statement. In the `finally` portion, the code can check and make sure the connection gets closed even if the code crashes.

Given this, the code below demonstrates how to read the Excel files. In the function below, the string array of Excel workbooks is passed in and a `DataSet` is returned where the `DataSets` `Tables` collection will contain all the read Excel worksheets.

The passed in string array will be used in the `foreach` loop. In the `foreach` loop we add the path to the file name from the array `workBookName` along with the `workSheetName`.

Build the connection string with the workbook name.
Set this connection string to the connection `con`.
Next, build the “select” command for the `OleDbDataAdapter` `sda`.
Create a new `DataTable` `tempDT` to fill from the select command. Then fill the table.
Finally add the filled `DataTable` to the `DataSet` `ds` variable.
After this code, the `DataSet` is returned.

Once you have this `DataSet` you can assign the grid to any one of the `DataTables` in the `DataSets` `Table` collection.

The code below demonstrates what is described above.

```
private DataSet GetExcelWorksheets(string[] workbooks) {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  string workBookName;
  string workSheetName;
  string constr;
  DataTable tempDT;
  OleDbConnection con = null;
  try {
    using (con = new OleDbConnection()) {
      using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter()) {
        foreach (string wb in workbooks) {
          workBookName = @"D:\Test\Excel_Test\" + wb;
          workSheetName = "Sheet1"; // "Table1";
          constr = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + workBookName + " ; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
          con.ConnectionString = constr;
          sda.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + workSheetName + "$]", con);
          tempDT = new DataTable();
          sda.Fill(tempDT);
          ds.Tables.Add(tempDT);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally {
    if (con != null) {
      con.Close();
    }
  }
  return ds;
}
```

Usage….

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string[] ExcelBooks = { "Book1.xls", "DemoTrainingData.xls" };
  DataSet ds = GetExcelWorksheets(ExcelBooks);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: JohnG, I’m at a loss for words because this is amazing! This is exactly what I’ve been looking for!!! You’re right, i have expressed that in rather complicated terms. I apologize for the inconvenience. For your trouble I would like to thank you cordially!!!